# Angular Material Autocomplete Floating Label Different Then Demo

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

Thanks for looking at this.

I am trying to recreate Angular Material demo for autocomplete with floating labels.

Shown here: https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete

My autocomplete field is not styling as the input-container does and I have looked through the documentation for md-floating-label and been unable to find anything that would guide me.

Current CodePen of Problem: http://codepen.io/ChrisHuie/pen/XbrZbd?editors=101

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="autocompleteFloatingLabelDemo" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column">
  <md-content layout-padding layout="column">
    <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
      <div layout-gt-sm="row">
        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text"/>
        </md-input-container>
          <md-autocomplete flex
              md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
              md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
              md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
              md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
              md-item-text="item.display"
              md-floating-label="Favorite state">
            <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
          </md-autocomplete>  
      </div>
    </form>
  </md-content>
  </div>
    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<body>

(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('autocompleteFloatingLabelDemo', ['ngMaterial'])
        .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
            .primaryPalette('green')
            .accentPalette('orange');
})
     .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);
  function DemoCtrl ($timeout, $q) {
    var self = this;
    // list of `state` value/display objects
    self.states        = loadAll();
    self.selectedItem  = null;
    self.searchText    = null;
    self.querySearch   = querySearch;
    // ******************************
    // Internal methods
    // ******************************
    /**
     * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
     * remote dataservice call.
     */
    function querySearch (query) {
      var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : [];
      return results;
    }
    /**
     * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
     */
    function loadAll() {
      var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
              Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
              Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
              Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
              North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
              South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
              Wisconsin, Wyoming';
      return allStates.split(/, +/g).map( function (state) {
        return {
          value: state.toLowerCase(),
          display: state
        };
      });
    }
    /**
     * Create filter function for a query string
     */
    function createFilterFor(query) {
      var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
      return function filterFn(state) {
        return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
      };
    }
  }
})();
```

I'm a newer programer and have spent all morning on this so any guidance is hugely appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This had to do with the cdn version, because when I went to rawgit for linking my CSS and Javascript it solved the problem. So this issue must have been addressed in more recent updates.

Updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/ChrisHuie/pen/XbrZbd?editors=101

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
</head>
```

.....

```
<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your two codepens are the same one. No one can look at the first one to see if they're experiencing the same problem.